# Bootstrap grid column divide dose not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started to use Bootstrap and I'm having trouble with the Grid Col System like below.

I want to center the logo and nav bar in the center of page so I divided the Grid layout with 4 col-lg-4 (md-4), then added the image and navigation bar into the second DIV col-lg-4 (please see the code) but when click on preview, the logo and navigation diviated a bit (but visible) to the left.

Can anyone help me to fix it, please. Thank in advance.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <img id="logo" src="PlayStation_1_Logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--main navbar-->
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2"></div>  
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index">Index</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="service">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/about-us">About-us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/news">News</a>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2"></div>
         </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this will resolve the problem, but  as a heads up, there's an extra closing `li` tag under the News `li` tag.

Comment: thanks for your kindly remind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code with below code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row text-center">  
        <img id="logo" src="PlayStation_1_Logo.png">
</div>
<!--main navbar-->
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">          
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder ">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index">Index</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="service">Service</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us">About-us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/news">News</a>
                        </li>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

also apply css on it as below :

```
<style>
        .navbar .navbar-nav {
            display: inline-block;
            float: none;
        }        
        .navbar .navbar-collapse {
            text-align: center;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked well. I thought that we need to use col 1-12 to algin anything, just now I realized from your code. Regards!